# Trying to stretch my video across my div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this video to stretch across the browser. It's placed inside of a div, but it won't stretch the rest of the div's width. It also will not respond to CSS. It only responds to inline commands. I'm new to this, and I've been searching for more than 2 day to find the answer. Hopefully you all can help!

Thanks.

Codepen:

See the Pen Portfolio Bones by Vincent Collins (@Tillix) on CodePen.

Comment: Welcome! But no one can help if you do not provide an example or your code. If you have a link to some codepen, give us the url.

Comment: is this the pen you are referring to https://codepen.io/Tillix/pen/GmBQPP

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, this is my codepen.

Comment: Why don't you put the video inside the div? Or have I understood that incorrectly?

Comment: Because, in the CodePen example, the video is not in the div.

Comment: It should be in the container div?

Comment: Well, you wrote: "It's placed inside of a div".